# How to get only one column data from firebase in android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to get the specific child values only using fire base.for example in mysql:
`Select table_name.title from table_name`

How can I achieve it in fire base using android ?

Answer (score 0):

When loading data from the Firebase Database, you're always retrieving full nodes. So if you want to retrieve a subset from the data, you'll either have to do it client-side or (more likely) create an extra list in the database with just the data you want to load.